# HELP - Não consigo identificar erro - PHP e SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Olá,
 estou tentando trazer em uma tabela o agrupamento de todas as etapas e item avaliação por ano, juntamente com a média das pontuações e pesos.

Consigo trazer apenas a última etapa e item p tabela, ou seja, não está fazendo o agrupamento, apesar do erro está apontando p outra linha (357 - marcada no código abaixo).

Exemplificação:

Tabela

etapa item pontuacao peso ano area (a área n é necessária)

A,item 1,2,4,2010

A,item 1,5,2,2010

A,item 1,3,2,2010

A,item 2,3,2,2010

A,item 2,3,2,2010

B,item 1,2,4,2010

B,item 1,5,2,2010

B,item 1,3,2,2011

E na tela, preciso que mostre:

etapa, item, AVG pontuacao, Avg peso, total, ano

A,item 1,3.3,5.3,17.49,2010

A,item 2,3,2,6,2010

B,item 1,5,4,2010

B,item 1,3,2,2011

Qualquer dúvida nas tabelas, pode perguntar. Tentei fazer de uma forma resumida

O erro é o seguinte:

( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp64\www\sistema line 357

Segue código abaixo:

```html
    <?php

        $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();


          $dados = $pdo->prepare("SELECT etapa, item_avaliacao,ano,AVG(pontuacao),AVG(peso) FROM item_avaliacao_pg GROUP BY etapa, item_avaliacao, ano");

          $dados->execute();

                  if($dados->rowCount()>=1){ 


              ?>


                
   <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Item Avaliação PG</h3>
              
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Etapa</th>
                  <th>Item avaliação</th>
                  <th>Nível satisfação</th>
                  <th>Pontuação(0-5)</th>
                  <th>Peso</th>
                  <th>Total</th>
                  <th>Ano</th>
                  
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <?php while($table = $dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                 ?>
                <tr>
               
                <?php 
                  
                  echo'<td>'.$table->etapa.'</td>';
                  echo'<td>'.$table->item_avaliacao.'</td>';
                //  echo'<td><img src="'.$table->nivel_satisfacao.'" height="42" width="42"></td>';
                  //echo'<td>'.$table->nivel_satisfacao.'</td>';
                  echo'<td>'.$table['AVG(pontuacao)'].'</td>'; //LINHA 357
                  echo'<td>'.$table['AVG(peso)'].'</td>';
                  echo'<td>'.$table['AVG(pontuacao)']*$table['AVG(peso)'].'</td>';
                  echo'<td>'.$table->ano.'</td>';
                  //Desativado
                 // echo '<td><a class="btn btn-app" href="editando-item-avaliacao.php?id='.$table->id_item_avaliacao_pg.'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Editar</a></td>';
                  
                  
                  } 
                    }

                    
                      ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>Etapa</th>
                  <th>Item Avaliação</th>
                  <th>Nível Satisfação</th>
                  <th>Pontuação</th>
                  <th>Peso</th>
                  <th>Total</th>
                  <th>Ano</th>
```

Obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro diz que um objeto não pode se manipulado como array. Colchetes são usados para acessar valores de um array ex `$usuario['nome']` para acessar propriedades de um objeto usa-se a seta (`->`) `$usuario->nome`.

O formato que o PDO retorna os dados está especificado no `fetch()` ser quer trabalhar com arrays mude:

```
$dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
```

Para:

```
$dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Também dê alias paras os campos com `avg()` assim fica um nome simples para recuperar depois.

Comment: Oi, amigo. Obrigada pela disponibilidade. Então, já tentei isso, mas aí ele mostra apenas os resultados numéricos, não mostrando item, etapa e ano.
Erro: ( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\Sistema  353
Essa linha é justamente da variável etapa.

Vou tentar criar dois fetch para ver.

Comment: Consegui resolver, eu tinha que pegar as strings dentro do while, por isso, que só estava pegando o último. Obrigada mais uma vez!

Comment: @IsadoraAlmeida ai você precisa mudar os elementos que tem `->` para usar colcehtes, `$table->etapa` vira `$table['etapa']`

Comment: Perfeito, @rray  é isso mesmo. Mas sem querer coloquei fora do while. Agora foi. Obrigada